# How to split varying url strings into substrings

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am attempting to split url strings into substrings so that I am only working with the domain name of the website e.g. `https://nodejs.org/api/console.html` should be `nodejs.org` and `http://postgresql.com` should be `postgresql.com`
I have tried solving this issue with the following line of code:

```
filePath[i].split('/').pop()
```

But this only works for the urls that do not contain files after the domain e.g. `http://postgresql.com`

How could I achieve this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript has a built in interface that handles URLs and their parts, aptly named `URL`.

You can create an instance of the `URL` using the source string and then use the `hostname` parameter to get the domain name.

The following snippet shows this in action:

```js
let urlString = 'https://nodejs.org/api/console.html';
let u = new URL(urlString);
console.log(u.hostname);
```

More information about the `URL` interface is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL), and specifically the `hostname` property [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/hostname).

Note that this is fully supported by all modern browsers and Node.js, but has limited support in IE.